# using cURL in lua

Tags: curl, lua

I am trying to use the curl library in a little lua script.

I know there is a "-k" option to disable the certification verification that curl does by default... but I haven't been able to find how to do it via code.

here's what I have so far:

```
  local cURL = require("cURL")

    headers = {"Accept: text/*",
               "Accept-Language: en",
               "Accept-Charset: iso-8859-1,*,utf-8",
               "Cache-Control: no-cache"}
    login_url = "https://10.10.2.1/cgi-bin/acd/myapp/controller/method?userid=tester&password=123123"

    c = cURL.easy_init()
    c:setopt_url(login_url)

    c:perform({writefunction=function(str)
                                succeed = succeed or (string.find(str, "srcId:%s+SignInAlertSupressor--"))
                             end })
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With new version of Lua-cURL[1] you can write

```
local cURL = require("cURL")

headers = {
  "Accept: text/*",
  "Accept-Language: en",
  "Accept-Charset: iso-8859-1,*,utf-8",
  "Cache-Control: no-cache"
}

login_url = "https://10.10.2.1/cgi-bin/acd/myapp/controller/method?userid=tester&password=123123"

c = cURL.easy{
  url            = login_url,
  ssl_verifypeer = false,
  ssl_verifyhost = false,
  httpheader     = headers,
  writefunction  = function(str)
    succeed = succeed or (string.find(str, "srcId:%s+SignInAlertSupressor--"))
  end
}

c:perform()
```

1 - https://github.com/Lua-cURL/Lua-cURLv3

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about **lua** and the corresponding cURL implementation. But to disable the SSL verification you need to set these options

`CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` and `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST`

And in `lua` i think you can set it using,

```
c:setopt(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER , false)
c:setopt(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST , false)
```

Comment: I'll have to hunt around because c:setopt() doesn't seem to work.  It returns an error message "attempt to call method 'setopt' (a nil value)'.