# Processing redirection string inside the NGINX script, is possible?

Tags: redirect, nginx

I am looking for a "full NGINX solution", withou intermediary redirection... But I need some external processing by "my Name-Resolver", as illustred with this `execute` fantasy:

```
server {
  server_name resolver.mydomain.com;
  execute xx = http://localhos:123456/myNameResolver/$request_uri;
  rewrite ^ http://www.adifferentdomain.com$xx? permanent;
}
```

So, is possible to do something like this? perhaps using a kind of `fastcgi_pass` but only to return a string, not to bypass all HTTP resolution.

Comment: See also [this question about user-defined functions in Nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51954762/287948).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can use [HttpLuaModule](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLuaModule), which can execute commands and store them in variables if needed.

```
location / {
  server_name resolver.mydomain.com;
  # Get response via lua script.
  set_by_lua_file $xx 'resolver-script.lua' $request_uri;
  rewrite ^ http://www.adifferentdomain.com$xx? permanent;
}
```

You just need a Lua script to do your request for you, try [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25888848/3399504) using your `$request_uri` as `arg[1]`, because it is being considered as a command line argument

Comment: But what the difference between LuaModule and usual Apache-modules or  Nginx's `fastcgi_pass` used for PHP, Python, etc.?   It is only a "language flavor", or  *HttpLuaModule* is a real fast complement and low-overhead for Nginx's HTTP processing?

Comment: You need to do something that a webserver is not supposed to do, which is embedding a second request response in the response itself. This is usually done by some kind of application, or by using PHP, Python etc. Lua is just a "native" NGINX solution.

Comment: Ops, before discuss... How to send a parameter (`$request_uri` at my illustration) to the function-call used by `$xx`?

Comment: Is a good answer (!), only a final check. There are also a "native" NGINX  [JavaScript Module](https://www.nginx.com/blog/introduction-nginscript/)...  Can I use `set_by_js_file` instead Lua?  Or this magic is only offered by Lua?

Comment: Not exactly. Check out [their API documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/njs/njs_api.html) down in the example section, maybe it will shed some light into your solution

Comment: You need to include a JS file with `js_include` then call a function from with `js_set` to get a variable into a resquest